# There is no pubspec.yaml file in android studio but project runs just fine how?

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec, pubspec.yaml, flutter-pubspec

[image]

There is not `pubspec.yaml` file how should I edit it now?
The project is running just fine without any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is click the Android button in the upper left corner and select the Project button. You will see `pubspec.yaml`. If you don't see `pubspec.yaml`, you can leave a comment.

Comment: I don't see it as of 8th October 2023.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter cannot run without `pubspec.yaml` file. You are just looking into the android file of it.

[Android View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqfMg.png)

[Project View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDEWU.png)

Instead of android choose project from the drop down menu and you can see `pubspec.yaml` file again

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have opened the android folder which is inside the main folder.

The flutter has the file structure as
[image]

The `pubspec.yaml` file resides in the main folder

Comment: It is opened default when I made a new project with flutter, using vs code works fine now.
Thank you for answering.